# VB.Net Webbrowser suppress script error not working on IE10 and IE11

Tags: javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control inside a VB.net windows application. Previously I was using 
"AddHandler CType(sender, WebBrowser).Document.Window.Error, AddressOf Window_Error" to suppress the script error. (Uncheck the IE disable script debugger). 
The above solution works on IE 9 and below. However, my clients have upgraded some of their workstation to IE10 and IE 11 and the script error popup again.

Lots of advice to use IOLECommandTarget and I have tested out using "http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311288" but I really have no idea how to use the EXEC method to suppress the script error in VB. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.scripterrorssuppressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `True`.